# How can I put in a laravel route in a js file

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

I have my javascript code in a js file that I include in my main layout.
I want to call ajax, to a specific named route. Becuase it is a js file, the blade syntax can't be run from there. 
I tried writing out the url, but the url changes depending on the route that is calling the ajax, so it's not pointing to the correct folder. 
I'd rather use a names route.
Any other suggestions?

Comment: Is the ajax triggered from a button, or...? Are you using jQuery, angular, or just pure javascript?

Comment: I am using pure javascript in an external file because there are alot of functions set up.

Comment: ok and how is the ajax triggered?

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered writing out all the named routes you'll need into the view? Perhaps make a hash of routes and just make the ajax call to the one you need at the time. Something like:

```
var routes = {
    'first': '{{ route('first') }}',
    'second': '{{ route('second') }}',
    // ....
};

// Somewhere later in code
$http.get(routes.second).then(function(result) {
    // do something
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your view file, define a global JavaScript variable:

```
<script>
var globalRouteName = "{{ $route }}";
</script>
```

And now, in your js file, simply use globalRoutName as variable.